# Stop auto joining channels in Slack

Tags: slack

How do I disable auto join in Slack? I keep getting invited into a channel that I don't want to be a part of and it's getting really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a misunderstanding. There is no auto-join feature in Slack (expect for people joining a Slack for the first time). So whenever you get invited into a channel its because a user or an app has explicitly invited you. It will say in the channel who invited you, so you know whom to contact.

Many companies have apps that make sure people stay in important channels (we have the same on our Slack). In that case you need to talk to the admin who runs the app.

Comment: the problem is that this is a "joke" channel and the admin finds it funny that I can't leave and reinvites me when I do. I'm not going to go to HR or anything, not worth the hassle and I don't want to get the guy in any serious trouble, but it is getting very annoying.

Comment: I sympathize. Unfortunately there is nothing one can do on the Slack side to protect against abusive behavior from an admin

Answer (score -1):

You can look into setting up a script that leaves a channel using the api: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.leave

Comment: Adding essential content of the link into answer would be more helpful. Link only answers would be invalid if link get changed.